# Bottom Sheet button custom style not working

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-dialogfragment, android-bottomsheetdialog

In my `BottomSheetDialogFragmen`t, I have a button, I want to make this button background rounded with a grey color border.

Here is my rounded background drawable "rounded_tranparent_background.xml":

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FFF" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#8A8383" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
 </shape>
```

I applied this background to my bottom sheet button.

Here is the bottom sheet layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFollowUnfollow"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_tranparent_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next_ltpro_medium"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Unfollow"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreyDark"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.71"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

    //...other code...

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 </layout>
```

Here is my style for the bottom sheet dialog

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

After applying all this code I couldn't able to achieve what I am looking for.
The design I am wanted is: [image: button design I am looking for]

and what I am getting [image: button design I am getting now]

how can I achieve my custom design at the button in bottom sheet dialog?

Comment: Why you are using <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> .  Instead you should use only topLeft and topRight .

Comment: Also, you can use custom UI for the "close". Use View below your ViewObject(close). Give background black color and it will be similar to above example

Comment: are you using the material components library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple `MaterialButton`:

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cornerRadius="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:textColor="..."
            app:strokeColor="..."/>
```

[image]

Comment: A key note is that widget theme definitions are set globally within the app main theme are ignored by `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, so we have to set desired theme in the xml definition of the widget explicitly (like the answer).

Answer (score 4):

This fix worked for me:

```
<Button        
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_tranparent_background"
    ...
```

Add both "android:backgroundTint" and app:backgroundTint:

```
<Button        
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_tranparent_background"
    android:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ...
```

Also my button theme definition is ignored in BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
<-- Themes.xml -->
<style>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">MyButtonStyle</item>

<!-- So quick fix: -->
<Button        
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_tranparent_background"
     android:theme="@style/MyButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use custom drawable for your button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="ResourceName">
    <solid android:color="@color/inside_color" />

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/border_color"
        android:width="3px" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

The output will be something like that

[image]

Comment: If you check my question, this portion of code is already there. The problem is behind the bottomSheetDialogFragment i think.

Comment: Unfortunately, bro, you have not wrote this code or you dont upload it. I have not seen your drawable. Instead, you are using style = "btnFollowUnFollow". You should use one of them. Not both of them. It does not work as you have sad. Change style to drawable then button will change.

Comment: check the very first portion of the question, I don't know how my code is different then yours......

Answer (score 0):

It appears that BottomSheetFragment is overriding your current theme so you must add this line of code inside Button. Worked for me.

```
<Button         
android:theme="@style/Theme.YOURTHEME"
/>
```